# Is there a way to get all open URLs from the browser from JAVA?

Tags: java, browser

I need to know what tabs are open in a browser, I was researching and found something about selenium, but it does not use the current section, it uses a session generated by it. Is there any other way to get open URLs from JAVA? . thanks for your help

Comment: I do not think that this is possible from Java, but you could write a google-chrome-extension that interacts with a Java application.

Comment: In a word, no, there isn't.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to make an application to monitor the tabs that have been opened in the browser